# Can I change my itinerary after getting a visa to enter Japan?

Tags: visas, japan, entry-permit

So, I have an Indian passport, and I applied for an internship visa to Japan. The visa was for less than 90 days. I had to show booking of flight in the documents. So, I had held booking for a connecting flight of Thai airways which lands in narita airport on 1st August. If my visa gets approved, can I book a different flight of All Nippon airways to which lands on 1st August as well but on Hamesa airport? I had to mention my port of entry into Japan in visa application form where I had mentioned Narita airport. Is that binding?

Comment: In normal times I’m pretty sure this wouldn’t matter at all. These days with lingering Covid rules, I’m not so sure…

Comment: Is there any place where I can confirm this, or some authority in Japan I cand directly mail?